# Store and fetch MD formatted data from Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, markdown

We are trying to store this data into Firebase which doesnt seem to be an issue using a String field

```
### Whether you’ve posted a task or you’ve completed one, what should reviews provide?

Well-written reviews should provide constructive feedback on your experience, helping community members make better-informed decisions.

### What should reviewers consider when writing a review?

Reviewers should consider whether they'd recommend the Tasker or Customer to other community members. It's important to be honest and clear in reviews.

### What are some aspects to consider in a review?

Here are some things to consider in a review:

- **Was the communication great?**
- **Were instructions clear?**
- **How accurate was the task description?**
- **Was the task performed to a high standard?**
- **Did you receive support throughout the task?**
- **Were the task outcomes met?**
- **Did you receive feedback during and after the task?**

### Can Taskers be rated on specific attributes?

Yes, Taskers can be rated on specific attributes such as punctuality and communication skills. However, it's important to leave a written review to elaborate on this.

### What if someone wants to remain anonymous when rating the other person?

If someone wants to remain anonymous, they can skip their written review and just leave a rating out of 5.
```

We are then using the Flutter Markdown package to attempt to render it, but seems to cannot see the newlines

```
class ArticleDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final String subCategoryDocumentId;
  final String parentCategoryDocumentId;
  final String articleDocumentId;
  final String title;

  const ArticleDetail({
    Key? key,
    required this.subCategoryDocumentId,
    required this.parentCategoryDocumentId,
    required this.articleDocumentId,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('helpCentre')
            .doc(parentCategoryDocumentId)
            .collection('subCategory')
            .doc(subCategoryDocumentId)
            .collection('articles')
            .doc(articleDocumentId)
            .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }

          var data = snapshot.data?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          var articleBody = data['body'];

          return Markdown(
            data: articleBody,
            selectable: true,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

We end up getting this
[image]

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the way you stored this text, not the way you're reading it.  We can't see that code or the actual document contents.

Comment: Firebase seems to store it all in one line

Comment: Firestore stores text exactly as you pass it to the API. The Firebase **console** doesn't handle newlines in the text very well though, so I'd recommend against to modify multiline text.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so this will likely be the issue as all the data has been directly inputted into the console

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen said, if you wanted to understand the difference write a script to update the document in Firestore instead of pasting the desire markdown into the Firebase console. You will then notice the line breaks are maintained as long as you do not edit it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase console doesn't handle newlines in the text very well, so I'd recommend against using the console to enter or modify multiline text.

Firestore stores text exactly as you pass it to the API though, so the best approach is to enter the text through code. I typically use a minimal Node.js script, and/or write a custom admin (web) page for this type of operation.